# internal reliability

Tags: ordinal-data, reliability, cronbachs-alpha

I have been searching for information on how to conduct internal reliability assessments but have been unsuccessful. Is there a book or website that can inform me on how to conduct these analysis? I have to measure the internal reliability on tasks that measure the response time of the participants.

Also, can I use the Cronbach's alpha in a task where the responses are open ended and are scored in 0, 1 and 2 depending on the accuracy of the answer? I was thinking about defining the values of the scores from 0-2 and treat it as an ordinal variables as one would in a questionnaire. Would that be acceptable?

---

Since you appear to be familiarised with psychometric tests, you may know that sometimes you are instructed to end the test after the child has failed a determined number of questions. Thus we end up with children who answered 30 questions and some who answered only 15, for example. When measurring the reliability of a task like the one I mentioned above where the child gets a determined point corresponding to the accuracy of his responses, do you score the asnwers he did not give as a 0 or just as an empty space? I am sorry if this is too basic.

Comment: Welcome to the site. There is no need to say "thanks" on any questions here. For better answers, you might want to discuss the specific applications you have in mind.

Comment: the applications of measuring the internal reliability? My study uses a great variety of psychometric tasks and batteries and since I am comparing three groups, I want to make sure the batteries I used are internally reliable so that my comparisons are more trustworthy. I could rely only on p-values or the effect size but is that enough? I cannot compare test-retest nor inter-rater reliability as only one investigator was involved and one session. I hope this asnwered your question, if not I can add what is missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Internal consistency (internal reliability) is a major topic in psychometrics in and of itself. Your best bet is a good psychometrics textbook. I recommend:

> Thorndike, R. M., & Thorndike-Christ, T. (2010). *Measurement and evaluation in psychology and education* (8th ed.). Boston, MA: Pearson. ISBN 0-13-240397-8.

To answer your specific question about Cronbach's alpha, yes, it's applicable in that situation.